# Show that all eigen values of the matrix are positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix $A=$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b &c \\b & a &0 \\c& 0 &1\\ \end{bmatrix}

where $a,b,c>0; b^2+c^2<a<1$

> Show that all its eigen values are positive.

**My try**:

I took the vector  **x**$=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and computed $xAx^T$ and obtained $xAx^T=x_1^2+ax_2^2+x_3^2+2bx_1x_2+2cx_1x_3$ but could not claim that $xAx^T>0$

I also found the characteristic polynomial of $A$ to be $x^3-x^2(a+2)+x(1+2a-b^2-c^2)+(c^2a-a+b^2)$.From here also I could not claim that all eigen values are positive .

Please give some way to solve the above problem

Comment: Sylvester's criterion?

Comment: Try Descarte's rule of signs?

Comment: @carmichael561 IIRC, the constant in the characteristic polynomial is det(A).  It is difficult to determine the sign of this particular expression.  Else both Sylvester's criterion orDescartes' rule of signs would be sufficient.

Comment: @DemetriP: The determinant is $a-b^2-c^2a$, which is easily seen to be positive based on the information given.

Comment: @carmichael561  It is likely  I am an idiot.  Thanks

Comment: @carmichael561; the determinant is positive implies that it has either two negative eigen values and a positive eigen value or all positive eigen values ;how can I conclude that the first case does not hold here

Comment: Look up Sylvester's criterion.

Answer (score 0):

To check symmetric matrix is positive definite , instead of cheaking sign of  eigenvalue, check sign of pivot element in echelon from, since number of positive pivot equal to number of positive eigenvalue, in this case all pivot  are positive by using given condition ,hence given matrix has all positive eigenvalues